# rollapply multiple times with different arguments

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean up my code a bit. Currently I run `rollapplyr` multiple times using different combinations of parameters. Here is the function I'm using it with:

```
library('assertthat')
var_sums <- function(x, sign) {
  assert_that(length(x) > 0)

  if (sign == "pos") {
    sum(x[which(x > 0)])
  } else if (sign == "neg") {
    sum(x[which(x < 0)])
  } else {
    stop("variable sign must have value of 'pos' or 'neg'")
  }
}
```

It takes in a vector `x` of positive and negative numbers between -1 and 1, and sums either just the positive ones or just the negative ones depending on the value of `sign`. Currently I've implemented it by doing:

```
library('zoo')
set.seed(1)
vec <- round(runif(100, min = -1), digits = 2)
pos_4 <- rollapplyr(vec, 4, var_sums, sign = "pos", fill = NA)
neg_4 <- rollapplyr(vec, 4, var_sums, sign = "neg", fill = NA)
pos_12 <- rollapplyr(vec, 12, var_sums, sign = "pos", fill = NA)
neg_12 <- rollapplyr(vec, 12, var_sums, sign = "neg", fill = NA)

y <- data.frame(pos_4, neg_4, pos_12, neg_12)
```

Surely there's a more elegant way of doing this that I'm just not seeing, using `do.call` or `mapply` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Data
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(20) - 0.5

# Parameters
signs <- c("neg", "pos")
n <- c(4, 12)
pars <- expand.grid(n=n, sign=signs, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
pars$name <- paste(pars$sign, pars$n, sep="_")
pars
#   n sign   name
#1  4  neg  neg_4
#2 12  neg neg_12
#3  4  pos  pos_4
#4 12  pos pos_12

# Function
f <- function(n, sign)rollapplyr(x, n, var_sums, sign = sign, fill = NA)
y <- mapply(f, pars$n, pars$sign)
colnames(m) <- pars$name
#             neg_4    neg_12     pos_4   pos_12
# [1,]           NA        NA        NA       NA
# [2,]           NA        NA        NA       NA
# [3,]           NA        NA        NA       NA
# [4,] -0.362367437        NA 0.4810612       NA
# [5,] -0.426194169        NA 0.4810612       NA
# [6,] -0.298318069        NA 0.8794508       NA
# [7,] -0.298318069        NA 1.2512727       NA
# [8,] -0.298318069        NA 1.0038627       NA
# [9,]  0.000000000        NA 1.1329768       NA
#[10,] -0.438213730        NA 0.7345871       NA
#[11,] -0.732239155        NA 0.2899118       NA
#[12,] -1.055682402 -1.716368 0.1291140 1.614038
#[13,] -1.055682402 -1.481877 0.1870228 1.801061
#[14,] -0.733364954 -1.469897 0.1870228 1.801061
#[15,] -0.439339529 -1.469897 0.4568643 1.998049
#[16,] -0.118197040 -1.472198 0.4568643 1.589841
#[17,] -0.118197040 -1.173879 0.4874599 1.807460
#[18,] -0.002300758 -1.173879 0.9793660 1.900976
#[19,] -0.122265578 -1.293844 0.7095246 1.456301
#[20,] -0.119964821 -1.293844 0.9869698 1.572948
```

Comment: Here is a minor variation of that: `g <- expand.grid(sign = c("pos", "neg"), width = c(4, 12)); 
    roll <- function(g) with(g, rollapplyr(x, width, var_sums, sign = sign, fill = NA)); 
    sapply(split(g, do.call("interaction", g)), roll)
`