# R - rollapply with multiple "by" values

Tags: r, zoo

I have trying to find an efficient way to do the code below:

```
library(zoo)
MaPrice <- function(x,N) {
    Mavg <- rollapply(x, N, mean)
    colnames(Mavg) <- "MaPrice"
    Mavg
}

Price.MA.1Hr <- MaPrice(out, 12)
Price.MA.2Hr <- MaPrice(out, 24)
Price.MA.4Hr <- MaPrice(out, 48)
Price.MA.6Hr <- MaPrice(out, 72)
```

The solution I came up with is the following:

```
MaPrice <- function(x,N) {
    MA <- matrix( ,nrow = nrow(x), ncol = length(N))
    for (i in 1:length(N)) {
        MA[,i]<- rollapply(x, N[i], mean)
    }
    MA
}

N <- c(1,2,4,6,8,12)

Price.MA <- MaPrice(Price, N)
```

> Price is a vector (ncol = 1)

This still provides the answer I am looking for, but I am looking to see if there is an alternate maybe an efficient way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: Already looked at the question "[rollapply multiple time with diffrent arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001209/rollapply-multiple-times-with-different-arguments)" on SO. Didnt understand the process.

Comment: It will be useful to link the already asked question you mentioned

Comment: What's `Price`?

Comment: Price is a vector.

Comment: @blackknight316 I've compared performance of solutions; unfortunately, I could not test your code because it was not reproducible

Comment: Which code are you talking about? I have two codes up there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the input vector is `v` this gives a zoo object `zz` whose ith column was formed using `w[i]`.  `as.data.frame(zz)` or `coredata(zz)` could be used to produce a data.frame or matrix respectively if needed.  `setNames(w, w)` could be reduced to just `w` if column names are not important.

```
# inputs
v <- 1:100  # data
w <- c(12, 24, 48, 72)

z <- zoo(v)
zz <- do.call("merge", lapply(setNames(w, w), rollmeanr, x = z))
```

or if a list of vectors is sufficient then:

```
lapply(setNames(w, w), rollmean, x = v)
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of setNames()?

Comment: `lapply` and `merge` will use the names to label the columns; otherwise, we get ugly column names.  Try it with `w` in place of `setNames(w, w)` to see the difference.

Comment: I did get ugly names when I did without them. Thanks for the help G!

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am newbie here. Just wanted to ask, is it okay as a programmer to use a code without understanding it fully? I fully didnt understand it but I can expect it to work in future.

Comment: I think if you look up each of the functions used `?do.call`, `?merge`, etc. and play with the examples at the bottom of the help pages you will get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

#### Reproducible data

```
N <- c(1,2,4,6,8,12)
set.seed(1)
Price <- data.frame(x=runif(20)*10)

#            x
# 1  2.6550866
# 2  3.7212390
# 3  5.7285336
# 4  9.0820779
# etc
```

*NOTE* `Price` can also be a vector and the solution works

#### Solution

Rewrite your function to return a data.frame with the `N` value used

```
MaPrice <- function(x,N) {
               Mavg <- data.frame(N = N, avg = rollapply(x, N, mean))
               Mavg
            }
```

You can use `purrr::map_df` to iterate through `N`

```
library(purrr)
Price.MA <- map_df(N, ~MaPrice(Price,.x))
```

#### Output

```
    N         x
1   1 2.6550866
2   1 3.7212390
3   1 5.7285336
4   1 9.0820779
5   1 2.0168193
# etc
```

#### Comparing Solutions

Since you might be interested in performance

Make `Price` a vector of 25,000 elements

```
N <- c(1,2,4,6,8,12)
set.seed(1)
Price <- runif(25000)*10

# parallel solution
library(parallel)
library(zoo)
PoGibas <- function(Price, N) {
               res <- mclapply(N, function(i) 
                         data.frame(i, rollapply(Price, i, mean)))
               # Final result
               do.call("rbind", res)
           }

# map_df solution
library(purrr)
MaPrice <- function(x,N) {
               Mavg <- data.frame(N = N, avg = rollapply(x, N, mean))
               Mavg
            }

CP <- function(Price, N) {
           Price.MA <- map_df(N, ~MaPrice(Price,.x))
       }

# mapply solution
out <- tbl_df(Price)
CArendt <- function() {
                mapply(function(x, n) {
                     rollapply(x, n, mean, fill = NA, align = "right")
                }, list(out), list(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12)) %>% tbl_df()
           }

# lapply zoo solution
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
GG <- function(v, w) {
         z <- zoo(v)
         zz <- do.call("merge", lapply(setNames(w, w), rollmeanr, x = z))
}
```

Using `microbechmark` to compare solutions

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(CP(Price,N), PoGibas(Price,N), CArendt())


              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max
      CP(Price, N)  298.7038  308.9860  345.8867  334.0053  377.5278  468.1461
 PoGibas(Price, N)  306.3882  319.5721  358.8717  372.9655  388.6214  488.5565
         CArendt() 2589.2316 2647.2216 2762.0759 2682.7357 2733.5398 8746.8235
      GG(Price, N)  785.3042  853.5904  876.4554  869.0996  895.1906 1010.1746
 neval
   100
   100
   100
   100
```

The **mean time of solutions is 353, 371, 876, and >2,000 ms**

Comment: Helpful performance comparison, thanks!  One note - although my proposal performs badly here, it is a native R solution (i.e. does not depend on other packages), if that happens to matter to anyone.  (disregarding the conversion to a `tbl_df`)

Comment: Agreed! I think it's important to keep multiple solutions because of the constraints of each user.

Answer (score 2):

As you wanted alternative efficient way, here's solution using `parallel`. I'm applying `rollapply` on `N` vector (no reason to loop), but instead of usual apply we're running those things in parallel.

```
# Packages
library(parallel)
library(zoo)
# Input
N     <- 1:4
Price <- 1:10
# Main computation
res <- mclapply(N, function(i) 
                   data.frame(i, rollapply(Price, i, mean)))
# Final result
do.call("rbind", res)
```

Comment: I couldnt install the package parallel. Is it still available?

Comment: @blackknight316 what do you mean by "couldn't"? What was your command and what error message did you get?

Comment: command - install.packages("parallel")
error msg - cant find the url

Answer (score 2):

So in the future, providing example data can make things easier for those who are trying to help.  Also, it can speed things up to include packages and `library` statements and such so that they can run your code verbatim.  (See the `reprex` package for useful tools in asking a good question).

I am a fan of using the `apply` family and list-based processing, so I would lean towards the following, along with `dplyr`.  Getting used to the `apply` family can make this sort of task straightforward.  Essentially, `mapply` loops over lists, applying the *i*th element to the *i*th call of the function (and recycling where needed).

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)


out <- tbl_df(randu[, 1])

## example with one
out %>% mutate(test = rollapply(., 12, mean, fill = NA))
#> # A tibble: 400 x 2
#>       value      test
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1 0.000031        NA
#>  2 0.044495        NA
#>  3 0.822440        NA
#>  4 0.322291        NA
#>  5 0.393595        NA
#>  6 0.309097 0.4633195
#>  7 0.826368 0.5074730
#>  8 0.729424 0.5794351
#>  9 0.317649 0.5804980
#> 10 0.599793 0.5593651
#> # ... with 390 more rows

## example with multiple, using mapply - basically just applying rollapply...
mapply(function(x, n) {
  rollapply(x, n, mean, fill = NA, align = "right")
}, list(out), list(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12)) %>% tbl_df()
#> # A tibble: 400 x 6
#>          V1        V2        V3        V4        V5    V6
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0.000031        NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  2 0.044495 0.0222630        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  3 0.822440 0.4334675        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  4 0.322291 0.5723655 0.2973143        NA        NA    NA
#>  5 0.393595 0.3579430 0.3957053        NA        NA    NA
#>  6 0.309097 0.3513460 0.4618558 0.3153248        NA    NA
#>  7 0.826368 0.5677325 0.4628377 0.4530477        NA    NA
#>  8 0.729424 0.7778960 0.5646210 0.5672025 0.4309676    NA
#>  9 0.317649 0.5235365 0.5456345 0.4830707 0.4706699    NA
#> 10 0.599793 0.4587210 0.6183085 0.5293210 0.5400821    NA
#> # ... with 390 more rows

## with lapply - probably more appropriate
lapply(list(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12)
, FUN = function(x, n) {
  return(rollapply(x, n, mean, fill = NA, align = "right"))
}, x = out) %>% setNames(., paste0("v", 1:6)) %>% do.call(bind_cols, .)
#> # A tibble: 400 x 6
#>          v1        v2        v3        v4        v5    v6
#>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 0.000031        NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  2 0.044495 0.0222630        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  3 0.822440 0.4334675        NA        NA        NA    NA
#>  4 0.322291 0.5723655 0.2973143        NA        NA    NA
#>  5 0.393595 0.3579430 0.3957053        NA        NA    NA
#>  6 0.309097 0.3513460 0.4618558 0.3153248        NA    NA
#>  7 0.826368 0.5677325 0.4628377 0.4530477        NA    NA
#>  8 0.729424 0.7778960 0.5646210 0.5672025 0.4309676    NA
#>  9 0.317649 0.5235365 0.5456345 0.4830707 0.4706699    NA
#> 10 0.599793 0.4587210 0.6183085 0.5293210 0.5400821    NA
#> # ... with 390 more rows
```

One last note - I definitely recommend avoiding `.` in your variable names, as the period is used for S3 class dispatch (and it has been painful to remove the periods out of all of my code written before I knew that handy tidbit).  [Further reading on style](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html)

Comment: So in hindsight, `lapply` is probably more relevant here since all you are really looping over is the `list(1,2,4,6,8,12)`... but I like `mapply` anyways.  :)